# SAS first.dot last.dot date calculation

Tags: sas

Attempting to create a variable that calculates the number of days between the current records date and the previous records date (grouped by `patid`). I am obviously missing something in my attempt, and I have unfortunately made of mess of things.

Any answers would be appreciated.

```
data sample;
informat patid $1. test_date mmddyy10.;
input patid test_date;
format test_date date9.;
datalines;
a 10/01/2005
a 10/05/2005
a 10/17/2005
b 10/02/2005
b 10/18/2005
b 10/22/2005
;
run;
```

I would like my data set to look like this:

```
data desire;
informat patid $1. test_date mmddyy10. dif;
input patid test_date dif;
format test_date date9.;
datalines;
a 10/01/2005 0
a 10/05/2005 4
a 10/17/2005 12
b 10/02/2005 0
b 10/18/2005 16
b 10/22/2005 4 
;
run;
```

My attempt:

```
data increment;
set sample;
by patid;
if first.patid then do;
dys_btwn_trmnt = 0;
end;
else do;
   dys_btwn_trmnt=dif(test_date);
end;
run;
```

Then I thought I may need retain, but no success -

```
data increment;
set sample;
by patid;
retain dys_btwn_trmnt 0;
if first.patid then do;
dys_btwn_trmnt = 0;
end;
else do;
   dys_btwn_trmnt=dif(test_date);
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of what happens when you conditionally execute a lag function (in this case the `DIF()` function).  The lag functions to do return the value from the previous observation. Instead they return the value from a stack that is created by executing the function.  By not executing the function for every observation not all values are placed onto the stack.

The simple solution is to run the `DIF()` function for every observation and then use the FIRST. condition to fix the value for the first observation in the group.

```
data increment;
  set sample;
  by patid;
  dys_btwn_trmnt=dif(test_date);
  if first.patid then dys_btwn_trmnt=0;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! That approach makes much more sense. +1 for the help.